# Apache still loading ioncube

Tags: php, apache, digital-ocean

I have a server in digital ocean.
I have removed zend extension line from php.ini in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and restared apache by

```
service apache2 restart
```

But in apache error log ( /var/log/apache2/error.log ) it is still showing this error

```
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20121212/ioncube_loader_lin_5.5.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20121212/ioncube_loader_lin_5.5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or dir$
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: check for other .ini files. lots of distributions will split modules out into their own "personal" .ini files, and they all get loaded by php at apache startup.

Comment: thanks man. This is what i did. searched from root 
"grep -r ioncube_loader_lin_5.5.so *"